# Find records in one table that aren't in another

Tags: sql-server

Ive got two tables. One has 102845 records, the other has 98496. I need to find the records that appear in the bigger table but not in the smaller table (4349).
These are how I create the numbers:

--98496

```
drop table #test2
select a.*, B.Delq_Sep12, b.Bal_Sep12, b.Queue_Sep12 
into #test2
from #test4 b
join pcd a on  (a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.account_number)
```

--102845

```
drop table #test1
select a.*, B.Delq_Sep12, b.Bal_Sep12, b.Queue_Sep12,
into #test1
from #test4 b 
left join pcd a on  (a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.account_number)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from #test1
except
select * from #test2
```

Of course, this assumes that all records in #test2 are in #test1

If you want to check the reverse, just reverse the query.

```
select * from #test2
except
select * from #test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your first query gets only matching rows from the two tables. The second one gets all rows from `b` while also pulling data from `a` where there is a match, and if there was no match, the `a` columns get filled with NULLs.

Now, the difference between the two result sets would effectively be the non-matching rows of `b`. And to get those rows, you could just use your second query with a NULL check like this:

```
select a.*, B.Delq_Sep12, b.Bal_Sep12, b.Queue_Sep12,
from #test4 b 
left join pcd a on  (a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = B.account_number)
where a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER is null
```

That is, no `#test1` or `#test2` is needed, just query for the non-matching rows directly.